# AngularJS how to append element to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to do an angular directive, which checks the height of an element, and if the height is given, I want to append another element to it. I'm new to Angular, so I dont know exactly how to do it. Here is a snippet of what I did so far:

the HTML:

```
<ul fadeouttxt>
    <li ng-repeat="cars in cars.list" style="height:200px;">
       <div>
          <div class="cnt">
            <h2>{{cars.title}}</h2>
            <div class="desc" ng-bind-html="cars.description"></div>
          </div>    
       </div>                   
    </li>
</ul>
```

the js:

```
.directive('fadeouttxt', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope) {
            $('div.cnt').filter(function() {
               if( $(this).find('.desc').height() < 130) return;
               $(this).append('<div class="fader"></div>'); 
            }); 
        }
    };
 });
```

the `<div class="fader"></div>` is a element which makes the overflowing text fade out...

So, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is this:

the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cars in cars.list" style="height:200px;">
       <div>
          <div class="cnt" fadeouttxt>
            <h2>{{cars.title}}</h2>
            <div class="desc" ng-bind-html="cars.description"></div>
          </div>    
       </div>                   
    </li>
</ul>
```

the js:

```
.directive('fadeouttxt', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            if( element.find('.desc').height() < 130) return;
            element.append('<div class="fader"></div>');
        }
    };
 });
```

so you don't need to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the documentation of the angularJS directive.

The second parameter of the link function is the element on which the directive is placed.

So, you can use the `element.append("<div></div>")` to put the div dynamically on the directive.

Like,

```
.directive('fadeouttxt', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $('div.cnt').filter(function() {
               if( element.find('.desc').height() < 130) return;
               element.append('<div class="fader"></div>'); 
            }); 
        }
    };
 });
```

You can check more from here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 0):

Use `element` argument which is passed to `link`

```
    link: function (scope, element) {
        $(element).find('div.cnt').filter(function() {
           return $(this).find('.desc').height() > 130;
        }).append('<div class="fader"></div>'); 
    }
```